# MySQL statment - add another condittion

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following statment:

```
$statement = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  `my_table` WHERE 
             `name` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            || `street` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            || `description` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            || `longname` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'  
                            ORDER BY id");
```

I would like to add another condition to search only in the row that `type` =500,600,700,800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`||` is a concatenation operator, I think you meant to use `OR` condition like

```
SELECT * FROM  `my_table`  
            WHERE (`name` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            OR `street` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            OR `description` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%'
            OR `longname` LIKE '%".$searchVal."%')
            AND `type` IN (500,600,700,800) <-- extra condition
            ORDER BY id;
```